# MySQL:2つのテーブル(table1:日付,値1・table2:日付,値2)を結合した際に、双方に存在しない日付の列を生成したい

Tags: mysql, sql

```html
select
  date,
  value1,
  value2
from 
    (select 
        t1.date as date,
        t1.value1 as value1,
        t2.value2 as value2
    from
        table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.date = t2.date
    union 
    select 
        t2.date as date,
        t1.value1 as value1,
        t2.value2 as value2
    from
        table1 t1 right join table2 t2 on t1.date = t2.date) t 
order by date
```

・テーブルデータ
table1　　　　　 table2
日付　 value1　　 日付　 value2
1/1　　 1　　　 　1/5　　 5
1/2 　　2　　 　　1/6 　　6
1/3 　　3　　 　　1/7 　　7

・SQL実行結果
date　 value1　value2
1/1　　 1
1/2 　　2
1/3 　　3
1/5　　 　　　　 5
1/6　　 　　　　 6　　
1/7 　　 　　　　7

上記SQLですと、1/4の列は両テーブルに存在しないため生成されませんが、下記のように1/4のデータも生成したいです。
　(つまり、最初の日付から最後の日付の間でスキップしている日付データを生成したい)
date　 value1　value2
1/1　　 1
1/2 　　2
1/3 　　3
1/4
1/5　　 　　　　 5
1/6　　 　　　　 6　　
1/7 　　 　　　　7

Comment: いきなり余談ですが、MySQL 8.0ではCTE(共通テーブル式)で再帰的に日付を生成できるようになります。 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-date-series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

連続した日付を生成し、それと外部結合してやれば歯抜けの表を補完できます。
mysql5.7までには連番を作る便利な方法がないので泥臭くなりますが、例えば次のようにしてやれば生成できます。

```
select date_add(str_to_date('2017/01/01', '%Y/%m/%d'), INTERVAL seq.row day)
from (
    SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row FROM 
    (select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t,
    (select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) t2,
    (SELECT @row:=0) t3
) seq
```

Answer (score 0):

閏年も考慮した日付マスターテーブルを作り、そのマスタに対象となるトランザクションのテーブルを外部結合でつけるのが一番楽なのではないでしょうか？
また、取り出したいデータの日付レンジの最小と最大の値を、対象となるトランザクションテーブルの最小値と最大値としない場合でも、日付マスターをwhere句で絞るだけなので簡単ですよ。